# Is there a way to show point labels in primefaces horizontal bar chart without using javaScript?

Tags: primefaces

I'm using primefaces horizontal bar chart model. Everything in the horizontal bar chart works fine except point labels.

[horizontal bar chart without point labels](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8o0aI.png)

As per primefaces horizontal bar chart, I'm able to show my values on mouse over via tooltip. But, i want to show values using point labels, so that i don't have to mouse over / hover everytime i want to see values.

[How i want to show horizontal bar chart with point labels](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mygZy.png)

What i found is - I can do it by using jqplot pointlabels with javaScript.

I just wanted to know if is there any way to do it without javaScript.
I have also found that there are methods like setShowPointLabels which can be used to show pointLabels. But they are using this method with limited set of charts like pie charts, etc. I couldn't work it out with horizontal bar chart.

So, if anyone has any idea about it or javaScript is the only way out with horizontal bar chart ??

Thanks

Comment: Please read [ask] and provide a [mcve]

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Have you found a solution for this one?

Comment: @ddc .. No, The requirement wasn't urgent & client didn't push for it. So, Didn't tried much later.